# c# saving strings to CSV file create blank inital row

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to save data to a CSV file, but then I open the file, the initial row (row 1) is blank.
If I remove any of the

> Environment.NewLine

statements, I either loose the column titles, or the data gets appended to them.

```
string CSVTitle = "Code,ID,Name,Booked" + Environment.NewLine;
string LineOneData = Code + "," + id + "," + Booked;
string csvFile = string.Join(CSVTitle, Environment.NewLine, LineOneData);
```

could someone advise me on how I have managed to create a blank first line, and on how to remove it ?

Thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't be generating your own CSV  files. There's a lot of subtle nuances that are easy to screw up - and there's no need in reinventing the wheel. Use a dedicated library that abstracts this away for you, such as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: Hi mason, I will in the next project, but I'm on a learning curve at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`string.Join()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) will concatenate a set of strings using a specified delimiter. In your case you specified `CSVTitle` as delimiter, and provided "`Environment.NewLine, LineOneData`" as set of strings to concatenate.

To fix the issue in your case you can simply re-order the arguments passed to `string.Join()`, and get rid of the first `Environment.NewLine` you're adding in the first line. So your solution might look something like this:

```
string CSVTitle = "Code,ID,Name,Booked";
string LineOneData = Code + "," + id + "," + Booked;
string csvFile = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, CSVTitle, LineOneData);
```

This way it will use "`CSVTitle, LineOneData`" as set of strings to concatenate, and delmit these strings by the `Environment.NewLine` string.

Comment: Hi bassfader , If I remove either of the `Environment.NewLine` s, then the lines either append, or I loose the titles

Comment: @GeraldOakham Ahhh I made a mistake, I confused `string.Join()` with `string.Concat()`... Sorry, updating my answer now.

Comment: bassfader: Nice. Thank you. I've selected this one as the answer as although @mm8 's trim did the trick, this one pointed out my error and pointed out the correct method. Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 4):

Trim the leading `Environment.NewLine`:

```
string csvFile = string.Join(CSVTitle, Environment.NewLine, LineOneData).TrimStart();
```

Or don't use `Join` at all:

```
string CSVTitle = "Code,ID,Name,Booked";
string LineOneData = Code + "," + id + "," + Booked;
string csvFile = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", CSVTitle, Environment.NewLine, LineOneData);
```